# Double cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, double

Having trouble with the if statement. It gives me the error "Double cannot be converted to boolean." 
Some help would be appriciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperatures {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Write your code here. 
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter a temperature: ");
            double value = reader.nextDouble();


            if ( value => 40 && value <= -30){
                System.out.println("Too high or low temperature, try again");
            }else{
                Graph.addNumber(value);
            }
            if (value == 00){
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Change if ( value => 40 && value <= -30) to if ( value >= 40 && value <= -30)

Comment: if(value >= 40 && value <= -30) will never true, use if(false) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change => to >= in your condition.

BTW, value cannot be both greater than 40 and smaller than -30, so you probably have another bug in your condition.

Change the && to ||, since you need conditional or, not and.

Answer (score 1):

```
=>
```

is not the correct operator for greater than or equal to.

```
>=
```

should work.

It seems that you want to test if the value is between -30 and 40 though, so you'd want

```
if (value >= -30 && value <= 40)
```

Comment: No sweat, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The operator in the first part of your if is wrong .It must be `>=` instead of `=>`

```
if ( value >= 40 && value <= -30){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //you had used =>, which is not any operator
if ( value >= 40 && value <= -30){
            System.out.println("Too high or low temperature, try again");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using if conditions for desired semantics (non erroneous input) first,

```
        if ( value < 40 && value > -30){
            Graph.addNumber(value);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Too high or low temperature, try again");
        }
```

Also note the casting (appended `D`) on the zero value

```
        if (value == 0D){
            break;
        }
```

or `value == 0.0` as possibly intended.

Answer (score 0):

Use  correct operator

```
if (value >= -30 && value <= 40)
```

[see this link](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-operator/)